# Gatsby Contentful graphql image

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-image

First question for something probably stupid but i really dont understand. I want some data from contentful for my gatsby site but i got an error who said "The fragment "GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG" does not exist." when i try to do the query with the fragment for contentful. I checked everything but im kind of lost yet. Thank you !

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac1dQ.png)
[Here is my query on graphql] When i console.log like this i got the url of the asset

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbcYo.png)

Comment: are you able to provide the code for the JS file your trying to do the query in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct answer but I used `...GatsbyContentfulFluid` instead of `...GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG` and it seemed to pull the image just fine